# How to implement "Front" method in a lock-free concurrent queue?

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to implement a concurrent lock-free queue. I am closely following this paper : https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf
But this paper doesn't provide a safe way to expose  Front() or Back() method. Enqueue() and Dequeue() methods are there. ( The paper elaborates a lock-free version and  also a version with locks, I am interested in the former). Let me get the question straight now. After all the safety checks (analogous to Enqueue), the crunch of the Front() function boils down to this:

```
1. if(local_copy_of_head == curr_shared_head) {  // Let's say I read this atomically. The equality means the head didn't move since the time I copied.
2.   return local_copy_of_head;
3. }
```

I want to make it clear that although this is a question about how to implement Front() function, but I am mainly interested in how to refactor the above snippet into an atomic block without any lock.
My concern is , if Thread1 gets interrupted after executing line no 1 ( I read this atomically let's say), then a second thread empties the queue, Thread1 gets rescheduled and returns a stale result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can make a crappy version that works a bunch of times, but in general is a fail. To peel the mystique of lock-free, replace it by its previous term busy-waiting. Busy-waiting more appropriately captures the choice of consuming cpu resources in the hope that your race end condition can be appropriately detected, so the results are consistent.

By giving away the head of the queue (Front), you have no idea how long the client of this might use it before committing to absorbing it (Dequeue, sic: that is not what dequeue means).  As such, your Front function can never be anything but a front for a poorly devised queue implementation.

Never is a pretty long time.   Ok, not never, but, it needs a companion function (Absorb) which can tell that this absorption of the head of the queue is the only operation on the head of the queue since the corresponding Front was called; thus the queue is in the same state.  If it was not, the caller has to be handed back a failure, in which it has to roll back whatever operation was in progress to reflect this failure.

Ok, so not never, but all that has been accomplished is to move the transaction semantics up a level, a hint to the designer that maybe the design is a bit lacking.  So you have a transactionless queue.   Some of us used to call that *increment*.